# Is it up to code (anywhere) to have a ground wire poking out the end of a wire nut?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, wire

A few days ago there was a [hot question about wiring with several pictures](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/180621/identifying-wires-behind-light-switch), here's one. Ignoring all the other issues with this wiring job, on the right hand side we see a green wire nut with the ground to the switch being stabbed through the top of the wire nut. I've only ever seen connections where all ground (or any conductors at all really) exit from the same side of the wire nut. Is this at all to code, and if so where?

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like all those light switches are wired incorrectly. They are switching the NEUTRAL side of the light whilst the HOT is feeding to the lights without being switched. This leaves the light socket hot even when the switch is off. As far as I know this is not up to code.

Comment: There is a second problem in that the GND wires from all the cables should be connected into the GND of the power input feed cable. As it shows now only the power feed in to power feed out have their GND wires connected and to the right most switch. I strongly suspect that the GNDs on the left and center switch only go to the light electrical boxes and have no safety connection back to the service panel.

Comment: Exactly what I see, switched neutrals.  This is dangerous and should be corrected immediately before somebody gets "bit" changing a light bulb.

Comment: That issue has already been  discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's up to code, and you will only find the top hole on green wirenuts that are only used for ground connections.

Comment: Yes, the instructions advise that use, and UL lists it that way.

Comment: Could end tragically in a TN-C installation. But then, most anything can.